# How to pass an existing repository instance to the next page in Flutter using the flutter_bloc package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have the following code that passes a bloc to the next page

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute<CreateFeedSelectClass>(
   builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
     value: BlocProvider.of<TeacheractivityfeedBloc>(context),
     child: CreateFeedSelectClass(imageStringList: state.selectedImages, imagePathList: state.selectedImagePaths, classList: state.classList,))
   )
);
```

I would like to pass this repository that was already created in this page before the build function

```
TeacherRepository _teacherRepository = TeacherRepository();
```

In the example from flutter bloc (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)
there is only a way to create a new instance, I want to pass the existing instance instead of creating a new one:

```
RepositoryProvider(
  create: (context) => RepositoryA(),  //-----> 
  child: ChildA(),
);
```

instead of
create: is there any way to do something like value: _teacherRepository like how we do it with BlocProvider.value(value:....) ?

Comment: can't we just use multi-provider to provider both bloc or repository.
If your following repository pattern this could be wrong way of doing. You can use GetIt pub to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a named constructor `value` available for `RepositoryProvider` which you can use.

```
RepositoryProvider.value(
  value: repository,
  child: Container(),
);
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you! couldn't find this in the flutter_bloc docs